# Swapping Perc 6/i with Perc 6/iR in Dell R710, invalid PCI card error

Tags: dell, dell-perc

I've got an old Dell R710 with a Perc 6/i storage controller card plugged into the internal storage controller slot. I've tried to replace it with a Perc 6/iR (which according to my information can do JBOD which the Perc 6/i cannot) but I get the following error message when I turn on the machine:

> Invalid PCI card found in the Internal Storage slot! System halted!!

That seems very odd to me given the fact, that the Perc 6/iR controller works in every other slot except the internal storage controller slot an also in different machines (tried it in a regular PCIe slot in a workstation). According to my knowledge the R710 could be equipped with a Perc 6/i, 6/iR or H200 controller on purchase, so does anyone have an idea what's wrong here?

PS: I've also tried and LSI firmware on the Perc 6/iR. Same result :(

Comment: The _obvious_ first thing to do is update the server's firmware, of course.

Comment: I agreee, and of course, the BIOS and the controller firmware are up to date.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "PERC 6/iR", are you referring to the SAS 6/iR card? If so, that should be completely compatible with your system... Try double-checking you have the correct part number though (YK838), and make certain that it's a SAS 6/iR, preferably one that was originally shipped in the same server "generation" or a server model that shipped w/ this same part (The same form factor of this card is used in the R710/610/510/900, similar tower models, and even the 1900 and 2900 series - uncertain if other revisions/version exist)

As others suggested, a BIOS update would also be a good first step, combined w/ the latest firmware (go with latest Dell firmware for best chances of compatibility).

Many people who run into this issue and report it to Dell end up having purchased an incorrect part, so try to be double-sure you have the right one... perhaps consider getting another on eBay, if even just to test with? Looks like they're plentiful and affordable there.

Comment: Just double checked and removed the card from the server, it's a JW065 which should be exactly the same as the YK838